# Best way to improve android webview loading performance for SPA

Tags: android, angularjs, webview

*Question*

I wonder what is the best way to make android webview perform best for the single page application loading.

*Situation*

I already have a web application with AngularJS.

Currently, I'm building an android application and use webview for the main view of that one.

This android application sends the http request every time when users click the menu on native side.

Sadly, webview loading is very slow since it always get entire resource from my web application, although one of great benefits of the single-page-application is url routing function without refreshing page entirely as I understand correctly. Below is my code for webview loading. Nothing changed I set `setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT)` though.

```
webviewFragment.java
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String url = getArguments().getString("URL");
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // handle url-scheme
    }
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // handle reaction for UI Component
    }
}
```

Comment: There are tools, like a firefox plugin, to inspect the loading on a PC. Then you can find specific issues (the 90% factor, the bottle neck) and have a before and after measure. And develop with cache off, like a client that comes first to the site and may leave forever as "the page does not load."